# How to remove empty item in Drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am passing a list to fill my drop down list.But first item of drop down list displaying as empty.How to remove this one?.

## What I have Tried

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Location", new SelectList(ViewBag.Locations), new { style = "width: 250px;" })
```

**Controller**

```
var lstLocations = db.ReviewsNews.Select(x => x.Location).Distinct().ToList();
            ViewBag.Locations = lstLocations;
```

Comment: The code you have shown will not show an empty option unless one of the `Location` values in `ReviewsNews` is empty.

Comment: what is the context of the list?

Comment: db is the context and ReviewNews is the table

Comment: Controller > var  lstLocations  contains empty entity ?

Comment: I don't know why you used Distinct here. Anyways is there a possibility that Location might be null? if so : `db.ReviewsNews.Select(x => x.Location).Where( x => x.Location != null).ToList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply remove the empty `Locations`:

```
var lstLocations = db.ReviewsNews.Where(o => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(o.Location)).Select(x => x.Location).Distinct().ToList();
ViewBag.Locations = lstLocations;
```

Comment: Perfect Solution,Thank You

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter is the "Option Label", looking at the description: "The text for a default empty item.  This parameter can be null."

It should remove the first blank item:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Location", new SelectList(ViewBag.Locations), null, new { style = "width: 250px;" })
```